Entity Framework Core 3.1 in a Webforms on .NET 4.7.2 app adds non-existent field to DB query
I have a simple WebForms app that I am migrating from Telerik DataAccess to Entity Framework Core 3.1.32. Almost everything is working fine except this. EF is adding a column to the query that does not exist and I cannot figure out why. I believe my naming conventions to be correct.
SQL Server table:

Data Class:
[Table("EntryAttendee")]
public class EntryAttendee 
{
    #region Database Properties

    [Key]
    public int EntryAttendeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PlayToWinEntryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EventAttendeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LikelyToBuy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GameRating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool AlreadyOwns { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool WantToWin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Relational Objects

    public virtual EventAttendee EventAttendee { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public EntryAttendee()
    {
        this.AlreadyOwns = false;
        this.WantToWin = true;
        this.LastUpdatedDate = this.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.Deleted = false;
    }

    #endregion
}

Captured DbContext call SQL:

Failed executing DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
SELECT [e].[EntryAttendeeId], [e].[AlreadyOwns], [e].[AttendeeId], [e].[CreatedBy], [e].[CreatedDate], [e].[Deleted], [e].[EventAttendeeId], [e].[GameRating], [e].[LastUpdatedBy], [e].[LastUpdatedDate], [e].[LikelyToBuy], [e].[PlayToWinEntryId], [e].[WantToWin]
FROM [EntryAttendee] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[Deleted] <> CAST(1 AS bit)

You can see it adds [e].[AttendeeId] to the query and I cannot figure out why. I added the [Key] annotation to EntryAttendeeId which did not fix it.

Do you have an Attendee entity as well? If so, check any relationship between that an EventAttendee. I suspect you have a one-to-one or many-to-one relationship where EF is defaulting to expect an AttendeeID FK on the EventAttendee where you intend an EventAttendeeId on the Attendee table. This may need explicit config to tell EF which table holds the FK. That or are missing the fact that a relationship is needed so EF is defaulting to what it expects.


I have a simple WebForms app that I am migrating from Telerik DataAccess to Entity Framework Core 3.1.32.

EF Core 3.1 is long out of support.  EF 6 (non-core) is the only supported version on .NET Framework. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/support#entity-framework-60-61-62-63-64-and-65
It would be best if you could migrate the whole app to .NET 8.

You can see it adds [e].[AttendeeId] to the query and I cannot figure out why.

Typically it's because you haven't configured it as the foreign key for the navigation property.  If the column were called EventAttendeeId the convention would have taken care of it.

I would love to go to .Net 8, but that would be at least a month of work.  I realize it is out of support.   EventAttendeeId IS a foreign key and there IS a property named for it.  EntryAttendee is the primary data table here, just querying the base table without relationships it ADDS AttendeeId and there is no logical reason I can see for it.

See if adding a ForeignKey attribute to the navigation property helps.  Otherwise, use EF 6.

I did try adding it, but it did not help

I followed the naming conventions.  This should be working.

To troubleshoot create a new standalone console app and add that entity and see if it behaves the same.

You mentioned EF6, when I tried to upgrade I get this:  Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.35'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I just created a shell with only the three classes in it and it behaves exactly the same way.  Starting to tear it down.

Found it.  Even though I was only calling the top class EntryAttendee, a reference in a relational class 3 levels down that worked in the model creation mappings with Telerik, was causing a circular reference in EF.  I was able to remove it and access that data a different way.
